# Customizing chosen jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to modify [this jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), I want to limit the total elements that are displayed in the textbox after selecting from the text box. I am currently moving the selected items to a div which is visible only when u click on a link.

this is what i have achived:

[image]

```
countCities++; if(countCities > 2){
    gonningToAppend = $('ul.chzn-choices li:visible').first().attr('id');
    cityName = $('ul.chzn-choices li:visible span').first().html();
    //alert(cityName);
    $('#invisibleCityContainer').append('<div class="'+gonningToAppend+' search-choice-todel'+'"><div style="display:inline-block;">'+cityName+'</div></div>');
    $('#invisibleCityContainer').append('<div id="'+gonningToAppend+'_close" class="x_button_for_city_list" ></div>');
    //$('ul.chzn-choices li:visible').first().appendTo("#invisibleCityContainer");
    $('ul.chzn-choices li:visible').first().hide();     

    $('#pluseCityCountInProfilePageEdit').html('and '+(countCities-2)+' more.');

  }
$( "#pluseCityCountInProfilePageEdit" ).click(function() { 
    $("#invisibleCityContainer").animate( { "opacity": "show"} , 1000 );
    event.stopPropagation();
}
);
```

HTML

```
<div id="invisibleCityContainer" style="display:none;" ></div>
```

what i want to achieve:

1. if you select more than two items the latest 2 items will be visible in the text box
2. all other selected items will be moved to a hidden div, when u click on show all selected
   the div becomes visible and we can deselect items.
3. once the items are deselected they have to repopulate in the drop down.

Comment: which plugin you are using? can you place code in fiddle to see how the things going on.?

Comment: Post updated, added reference to the plugin